# Create a file on different mobile phones in Qt

Tags: android, ios, qt, mobile, filesystems

I want to create a cross-platform application. It does not belong to any particular tablets or smartphones. It is supposed to be run on any device. However, I want to create a file on devices. The problem is that I do not know where to save it. Because it is cross-platform, I cannot specify any path for that file. Any idea how to do such save process independent from any specific platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qt provides the nice class [`QStandardPaths`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). Directly from the docs:

> The QStandardPaths class provides methods for accessing standard paths.
>   This class contains functions to query **standard locations** on the local filesystem, for common tasks such as user-specific directories or system-wide configuration directories.

In particular you should use the static method:

```
QStringList QStandardPaths::standardLocations(StandardLocation type)
```

A common usage can be defined for the home directory as follows:

```
QString basePath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)[0]
```

Note that I've queried the returned `StringList` for the first entry, without checking if it is empty. *That's safe* since the returned object is **never** empty for the home location! That's not always the case but the docs are quite detailed about that and also about which locations are returned on each specific platform. Note also that, if not specified differently (see again the docs for specific cases), the first entry returned in the `StringList` is always the **writable** one.

As of Qt 5.5 the documentation is *complete* for what concerns iOS and Android. That's because on newer Qt versions the iOS file system is *correctly and completely* supported. That was not true for versions minor than 5.2 (see for instance the closed [QTBUG-34199](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34199) but also read [QTBUG-36171](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36171) for more details about iOS `QStandardPaths` support throughtout Qt releases cycle).

Finally, an advice. If you are interested in *sharing* files between an android/iOS device and a PC via USB, a good location choice can be `QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation`. Mind that in iOS additional policies for file sharing must be defined, i.e. `UIFileSharingEnabled` key must be set in the info plist of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You should save your file in `HOME/yourdirname/`. You can use [`QDir`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) to make dirs, access them, etc. `QDir` is system independent and provides also the function [`homePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath) which returns the absolute path to the home directory.